# Flattening promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

The bluebird library seems to automagically use `Promise::then` both as an equivalent of "map" and "flatMap" on the promise, eg see this example.

```
var Promise;

Promise = require('bluebird').Promise;

Promise.resolve(1).then(function(x) {
  return Promise.resolve(x + 1);
}).then(function(x) {
  return console.log(x); // => `2` (not a promise)
});

Promise.resolve(1).then(function(x) {
  return x + 1;
}).then(function(x) {
  return console.log(x); // => `2`
});

Promise.reject('hi').catch(function(x) {
  return Promise.reject('hi2');
}).catch(function(x) {
  return console.error(x); //  => `hi2` (not a promise)
});
```

Is this a contract of the es6 Promise API? I see no mention of this flattening behavior [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn802833(v=vs.94).aspx), for example.

Comment: Uh, those docs are *very* sparse. MSDN doesn't even mention that `then` returns a promise :-/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is this a contract of the es6 Promise API?

Yes, it is a contract established by [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/), and has made its way from there into the ES6 specification. You will find some discussions [here](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/101), [here](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/97) and [here](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94).